# email issue with case assignment rules in playground

Tags: assignment-rules

I've created a case assignment rule using queues. When it fires, the case gets assigned to the proper queue and an email is sent out to the appropriate queue members, but the email is *not* the email template that I specified in the assignment rule, it's the standard "case notification" email (the one that reads "Case 00000000 has been assigned to you. Please click on the link below to view the record." and then has a link to the record).

Deliverability is set to all, 'send email to members' is checked in the queues, and the email template is properly assigned in the assignment rules.

I'm doing this in a trailhead playground, so I'm assuming that it's just some limitation of the playground, but maybe someone knows a better answer?

Just to add a little more weirdness, the identical scenario in Lead assignment rules has no issues, the emails are sent using the template.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what the issue is. When a lead is created manually and assigned using the assignment rule, Salesforce takes one action - it assigns the lead, so the email based on the template is sent [image: feed from lead creation] But when a case is created manually and assigned there are two actions that take place. First it assigns it to the person manually creating the case, and then it reassigns using the assignment rule. [image: feed from case cretion] Since it’s a reassignment and not a creation, no template email is sent. Why that's the default behavior is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

*It has nothing to do with Playground orgs*

Notifications on case assignment are influenced by [Service Cloud Support Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_supportrules.htm&type=5) found in `Setup`

> Notify Default Case Owner -- Notify the default case owner when a case is assigned to that user. If the new owner is a queue, the notification is sent to the queue email address. Notifications are system-generated and can't be modified.

Comment: Thanks, croprredy. That explains the notification email, but I still don't get why the email template that I've specified is not also being sent (and 'Send Email to Members' is checked).

Comment: `Notifications are system-generated and can't be modified.`

Comment: I've figured out what the issue is. When a lead is created manually and assigned using the assignment rule, Salesforce takes one action - it assigns the lead, so the email based on the template is sent [link](https://i.imgur.com/cXUdeKI.png) But when a case is created manually and assigned there are two actions that take place. First it assigns it to the person manually creating the case, and then it reassigns using the assignment rule. [link](https://i.imgur.com/AMlhtck.png) Since it’s a reassignment and not a creation, no template email is sent

Comment: @zargosh - as a service to the community, write up an answer and then accept it